# having issues greping variables in linux

Tags: linux, grep, find

Below is the code I am trying:

```
{    
echo "Enter dirname and hit Return"
read input1
echo "Enter a pattern to be searched for in the current directory"
read input2
find /*/${input1}/*/logs/*/*/*/* -name '*.gz' -exec sh -c 'gzip -cd "$0" | grep -- "${input2}"' {} \;
}
```

while the input1 matches but the input2 doesnt seem to match and I am getting all the outputs of input1 without getting input2 matched with it.

purpose is to read all the .gz files and get the keyword input2 match.

Comment: the only problem is while I try to run the above in script. 
If I try to run the command in bash, it works!

find /*/input1/*/logs/*/*/*/* -name '*.gz' -exec sh -c 'gzip -cd "$0" | grep -- "input2"' {} \;
it works when I dont go for variable.

Comment: Use bash -x to debug the script.

Comment: Likely the single quotes around the find/exec are preventing expansion of input2

Comment: You need to `export input2` for it to be available to `sh`. Also add `-r` to `read` for it not to treat backslash specially. Add `IFS=` for `read` not to strip leading and trailing blanks. (and quote `$input1`)

Comment: Thanks for the response folks. I am a network(firewall/routing/switching) guy just trying my hand in scripting. Modifying the quotes isnt helping. Could you please type the last line of my code, which you want me to try.

Comment: `sh -c 'gzip -cd "$1" | grep -- "$2"' _ {} "$input2"`

Comment: Have you considered using `zgrep` instead?

Comment: Unfortunately both the above didnt work!

Comment: If I run the script as follows ---> find /*/${input1}/*/logs/*/*/*/* -name '*.gz' -exec sh -c 'gzip -cd "$0"' {} \;

and then do ---> bash code.sh | grep input2 ,

it works fine.

the problem is somewhere within this part ---> 'gzip -cd "$0" | grep -- "${input2}"'

Comment: is there as way I can assign the find output to a value:
i = find /*/${input1}/*/logs/*/*/*/* -name '*.gz' -exec sh -c 'gzip -cd "$0";

Then try to grep input2 from the value e.g., i as per above sample.
Can someone show me the syntax of the code.

something like:
echo $i | grep $input2

Answer (score 0):

The "internal" script that `find` calls does not have access to the `$input2` variable.

You may instead do

```
find /*/"$input1"/*/logs/*/*/*/* -name '*.gz' \
    -exec sh -c 'gzip -cd "$1" | grep -e "$0"' "$input2" {} \;
```

This passes the value of `$input2` into the internal script and will make it available as `$0` while the filename argument will be `$1`.

Alternatively, just let `find` decompress the files and filter the output from `find` as a whole:

```
find /*/"$input1"/*/logs/*/*/*/* -name '*.gz' \
    -exec gzip -cd {} + | grep -e "$input2"
```

---

Since `find` already enters into all subdirectories of the given top-directory, you can probably leave out some of the filename globs and instead use `-mindepth 4` (if your `find` supports this option), and add `-type f` to signal that you're only interested in regular files:

```
find /*/"$input1"/*/logs -mindepth 4 -type f -name '*.gz' \
    -exec gzip -cd {} + | grep -e "$input2"
```